# Covariate dependent Markov models? Plot state transition probability along gradient of covariate values

Tags: r, markov-chains, markov-models

Data consists of 4 variable, id, x1 and x2, continuous variables which are correlated with y, a binary variable. 0 and 1 in the binary variable represent different states. Is it possible to use Markov chain models to calculate and plot state transition probability along the gradient of covariate values for each id and subsequently for the pooled data?

```
set.seed(1)
id =rep(1, 100)
x1 = rnorm(100)           
x2 = rnorm(100)
z = 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2      
pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))        
y = rbinom(100,1,pr)
a<-data.frame(id,x1,x2, y)


set.seed(2)
id =rep(2, 100)
x1 = rnorm(100)           
x2 = rnorm(100)
z = 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2      
pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))        
y = rbinom(100,1,pr)
b<-data.frame(id,x1,x2, y)


set.seed(3)
id =rep(3, 100)
x1 = rnorm(100)           
x2 = rnorm(100)
z = 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2      
pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))        
y = rbinom(100,1,pr)
c<-data.frame(id,x1,x2, y)


d<-rbind(a,b,c)
```

Comment: What do you mean by along the gradient of covariate values? Can you add an example of expected output?

Comment: @Freguglia, To see how probability of state switching changes at different covariate values. I can put link here to [some pictures](https://www.google.com/search?q=state+transition+probability+covariate&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiwzPvN_IHrAhVBM-wKHat0AtYQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=state+transition+probability+covariate&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1DBRViJXGC0XmgAcAB4AIABSIgB2AWSAQIxMZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=ZI0pX7CKL8HmsAer6YmwDQ&bih=625&biw=1366&rlz=1C1CHBF_enCZ907CZ907#imgrc=AjiBtiQdm2s9-M) I have found?

Comment: Yes! That would help!

Comment: You seem to be asking about modeling advice rather than a specific programming question. You should instead ask at [stast.se] where statistical questions are on topic. If you know what method/technique you should use but can't figure out how to do it in R, then you might consider asking here.

Comment: @MrFlick, thank you, will try, just to ask you, what is [stast.se]? Googling it doesn't do much.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Typo. That was supposed to be stats.se which in brackets expands to Cross Validated’s url: [stats.se] When posting there I might leave out lengthy code chucks and describe the data and type of estimates you want to be able to make.